# How to cancel an async query the right way

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

This is a follow up question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059275/ef-5-how-to-cancel-a-longrunning-query-in-a-async-task).

I'm trying to load data from my database which will take 5-10 seconds, but I want the GUI to stay responsive and also it should be cancellable.

```
private CancellationTokenSource _source;

public IEnumerable<Measurement> Measurements { get { ... } set { ... } }

private async void LoadData()
{
    _source = new CancellationTokenSource();

    using (var context = new TraceContext())
    {
        Measurements = null;
        Measurements = await context.Measurements.ToListAsync(_source.Token);
    }
}

private void Cancel()
{
    if (_source != null)
        _source.Cancel();
}

public RelayCommand ReloadCommand
{
    get { return _reloadCommand ?? (_reloadCommand = new RelayCommand(Reload)); }
}
private RelayCommand _reloadCommand;

public RelayCommand CancelCommand
{
    get { return _cancelCommand ?? (_cancelCommand = new RelayCommand(Cancel)); }
}
private RelayCommand _cancelCommand;
```

I've tried a few things, but I just can't get this to work properly, this just loads the List and thats all, I can't cancel this.

Where is the error in this?

Comment: When you say "I can't cancel this" what actually happens when you tell the `CancellationTokenSource` to cancel?

Comment: Nothings happens, as far as I've got the concept behind this it should throw an exception if there is still a task running with this token, but this doesn't happen.

Comment: What is `ToListAsync`? From a bit of googling, I can't find it as part of MSDN or something. Maybe you wrote it and it contains a bug, so that the token is not being applied correctly?

Comment: That's not how cancellation works. An exception is thrown by a cancelled task (a `Task` which has transitioned to the `Cancelled` state) only if an attempt is made to `Wait()` for the task or observe the result of the task. In this case, the task is controlled by EF and will only transition to that state if EF chooses to. Without knowing their internal details, the beta version may not do this.

Comment: @TimS. this is part of the new EF6 functions http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819165.aspx

EDIT: http://goo.gl/kMR5D maybe a better source

Comment: @Tragedian `.ToListAsync` does return a Task (but it still could be the case that this isn't implemented in beta 1, although it would be weird)

Comment: It is possible that the EF6 query is in fact happening very fast, and it's taking several seconds to *load the results in the UI*. Can you stick a `Stopwatch` around the EF6 query (before you assign it to `Measurements`) and see how fast it's actually executing?

Comment: @StephenCleary when I run the query in plain sql `select * from Measurement` it takes about 7 seconds

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up. Currently the implementation of this async API in EF relies on the underlying ADO.NET provider to honor cancellation, but SqlDataReader.ReadAsync has some limitations and we have observed that in many cases it won't cancel immediately when cancellation is requested. We have [a bug](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1470) that we are considering for fixing in EF6 RTM that is about introducing our own checks for the cancellation requests between row reads inside the EF methods.

In the meanwhile you can workaround this limitation by using ForEachAsync() to add items to the list and check on every row, e.g. (not thoroughly tested):

```
    public async static Task<List<T>> MyToListAsync<T>(
        this IQueryable<T> source,
        CancellationToken token)
    {
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        var list = new List<T>();
        await source.ForEachAsync(item =>
        {
            list.Add(item);
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        });
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: I've tried this now and it works, but only after the data is loaded (checked with wireshark all data is loaded, but the filling of the list is cancelled). Also I think `ForEachAsync` should also be called with the `CancellationToken` => `source.ForEachAsync(..., token)`, but it seams like `ForEachAsync` also isn't implementing the Cancellation pattern in the right way, because data is still loaded and it won't throw an exception.

Comment: The bug I mentioned is about adding cancellation request checks inside ForEachAsync, so that part should be addressed when we fix the bug. Another aspect that is interesting is that since in EF6 we are buffering query results by default, the loading of the datareader (i.e. the calls to ReadAsyc) happen one level below before we start materializing results. I will add this detail to the bug so that we consider it when fixing the bug.

Comment: By the way, to avoid the full results from being loaded you can add .AsStreaming() to the query. This will have other consequences, e.g. streaming queries are not compatible with the connection resiliency feature.